# Bus Error 10 from Importing Python Module

Tags: memory-management, python-import

I installed the gdal module for python a week ago, via the GDAL Complete 1.11 Framework Package. I wrote a program which relied heavily on gdal and osgeo and ogr to work with shapefiles (.shp) and rasters (.TIF). Today, without changing my code at all, when I ran it in the terminal as I usually do, I got back:

```
Bus error: 10
```

Since I hadn't changed anything with my code, I looked to see whether the problem was with one of my imports. When I commented everything out besides

```
from osgeo import ogr, gdal
```

I got the same error, similarly for when I just ran python in the terminal and tried

```
import gdal
```

I read that Bus Errors are caused by non-existent memory addresses, so I thought the module might somehow not be there anymore, so I listed my modules using

```
["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()]
```

and gdal was listed in there. Anyway, that wasn't necessarily the best thought since python throws an ImportError for modules it doesn't recognize. Other imports, like numpy, math, time, and datetime all work for me. Since bus errors are a sort of hardware fault with the memory, I tried a soft and then a hard reboot, still getting the same bus error. In fact, since I restarted my computer, it's been dreadfully slow. So my first question is why the Bus Error occurred and how to fix it, and second, I'm wondering how to get my computer back up to speed.

Last night, I dropped my computer in its case, but gdal (and seemingly everything else) was working fine this morning, until this error came about.

I appreciate your time and input.

Comment: Bus errors are also caused by flaky hardware.